# Firebase invite API SnackBar

Tags: android, firebase-invites

I am using the Firebase Invite API which is working pretty good. But the SnackBar telling me that the invitation has been sent is hiding my floating action button.
Is there a way to make the FAB move up when the SnackBar gets poped up?

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem where the snackbar overlaps the button you can follow this tutorial: https://medium.com/@phaniraja/overlap-issue-with-snackbar-df49e25be407#.97shcgbbf

I think it is exactly the same problem as yours.